# Removal of file extensions from satellite area of wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm requiring help with a small htaccess problem I've run into.

My site primarily runs on Wordpress, installed at the root.  However I have introduced a new area to the site which is built external to WordPress.  This area of the site sits within a directory at the root of the site.

What I'm struggling with is the removal of file extensions for files contained within this directory.  I also require a trailing salash and the necessary redirects.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To hide PHP file extensions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

You can add other file extensions here if need be.

Could you clarify the question a bit more? Not sure what you mean by this:

> I also require a trailing salash and the necessary redirects.